# Put a Delay in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to add a delay of about 100 miliseconds to my Javascript code but I don't want to use the `setTimeout` function of the `window` object and I don't want to use a busy loop.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why setTimeout isn't appropriate/doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: @eyelidessness sometimes inserting a setTimeout(...) it might involve having to update a whole load of unit tests, using jest fake timers etc.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Unfortunately, `setTimeout()` is the only **reliable** way (not the only way, but the only **reliable** way) to pause the execution of the script without blocking the UI.

It's not that hard to use actually, instead of writing this:

```
var x = 1;

// Place mysterious code that blocks the thread for 100 ms.

x = x * 3 + 2;
var y = x / 2;
```

you use `setTimeout()` to rewrite it this way:

```
var x = 1;
var y = null; // To keep under proper scope

setTimeout(function() {
    x = x * 3 + 2;
    y = x / 2;
}, 100);
```

I understand that using `setTimeout()` involves more thought than a desirable `sleep()` function, but unfortunately the later doesn't exist. Many workarounds are there to try to implement such functions. Some using busy loops:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

others [using an `XMLHttpRequest` tied with a server script that sleeps for a amount of time before returning a result](http://narayanraman.blogspot.com/2005/12/javascript-sleep-or-wait.html).

Unfortunately, those are workarounds and are likely to cause other problems (such as freezing browsers). It is recommended to simply stick with the recommended way, which is `setTimeout()`).

Comment: **@James M.:** Totally Agree... I never understood why there is such a big stigma around `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I don't believe setTimeout() has any stigma surrounding it, its just that it doesn't always produce the desired effect easily.

Say, for instance, if you want to idle the processor for a short period of time while in a process intensive loop to avoid locking up the browser. Achieving this result with setTimeout can be difficult for inexperienced JavaScript programmers.

Comment: That script works for me up to around 9 seconds. After that it stays around 9 seconds. Maybe it's that `1e7` value?

Comment: "but unfortunately the later doesn't exist." Did you mean to say "latter"?

Comment: Im new to js. How would I call the above delay script? I have a loop im trying to delay using this function. I tried function sleep (2000){...}. But that's not working.

Comment: @user982853 Simply `sleep(2000)`. But, don't use it, because of the reasons explained in the answer

Comment: For anybody using node.js it is worth noting this would be asynchronous, so your code will first continue executing past the setTimeout call and then do the actual statements within it later.

Comment: This is the ideal method for "putting a delay in javascript". It might not be "browser friendly" but when you are debugging code, sometimes you need to break the browser and thus, the reason for a sleep function. I cant think of any other use for sleep function except making the code really really slow so the customer thinks it looks "even faster" when they come to see the progress. :)

Answer (score 35):

If you're okay with ES2017, `await` is good:

```js
const DEF_DELAY = 1000;

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms || DEF_DELAY));
}

await sleep(100);
```

Note that the `await` part needs to be in an async function:

```js
//IIAFE (immediately invoked async function expression)
(async()=>{
  //Do some stuff
  await sleep(100);
  //Do some more stuff
})()
```

Comment: i like this one

Answer (score 17):

I just had an issue where I needed to solve this properly.

Via Ajax, a script gets X (0-10) messages.
What I wanted to do:
Add one message to the DOM every 10 Seconds.

the code I ended up with:

```
$.each(messages, function(idx, el){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    doSomething(el);
  },Math.floor(idx+1)*10000);
});
```

Basically, think of the timeouts as a "timeline" of your script.

This is what we WANT to code:

```
DoSomething();
WaitAndDoNothing(5000);
DoSomethingOther();
WaitAndDoNothing(5000);
DoEvenMore();
```

This is HOW WE NEED TO TELL IT TO THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
At Runtime 0    : DoSomething();
At Runtime 5000 : DoSomethingOther();
At Runtime 10000: DoEvenMore();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer explaining SetTimeOut behavior. The issue is that later on when the code is long, or depends on server responses, it becomes difficult to even visualize the actual timeline in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Actually only `setTimeout` is fine for that job and normally you cannot set exact delays with non determined methods as busy loops.

Comment: You cannot pause the js interpretor with setTimeout.

Comment: You can only call a function after a delay. setTimeout is not 'blocking'. The rest of the code works as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/javascript-sleep-function-t66049.html) has a good discussion and a useful solution:

```
function pause( iMilliseconds )
{
    var sDialogScript = 'window.setTimeout( function () { window.close(); }, ' + iMilliseconds + ');';
    window.showModalDialog('javascript:document.writeln ("<script>' + sDialogScript + '<' + '/script>")');
}
```

Unfortunately it appears that this doesn't work in some versions of IE, but the thread has many other worthy proposals if that proves to be a problem for you.

Comment: Seems like a solution waiting for a problem. I can't think of a single situation in which `setTimeout` would not do its job. But +1 for creativity. :)

Answer (score -13):

Use a AJAX function which will call a php page synchronously and then in that page you can put the php usleep() function which will act as a delay.

```
function delay(t){

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}

else

{// code for IE6, IE5

xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.hklabs.org/files/delay.php?time="+t,false);

//This will call the page named delay.php and the response will be sent to a division with ID as "response"

xmlhttp.send();

document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
```

http://www.hklabs.org/articles/put-delay-in-javascript

Comment: Don't forget the basics of web design. The fundamental principle is to reduce server load as much as you can. For a simple time delay you are requesting a page from the server infinite number of times. Just think about what you are doing here.

Comment: You've killed him