# How to pause JavaScript code execution for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to stop execution for 2 seconds.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> HW 10.12 </title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
             document.write(i);
             sleep(2); //for the first time loop is excute and sleep for 2 seconds        
         };
      </script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

For the first time loop is excute and sleep for 2 seconds. I want to stop execution for two seconds?

Comment: for (var i = 1; i <=5; i++)
{
 
   document.write(i);
   sleep(4);
 
   
  
}

Comment: Why do you want to pause execution for two, or any number of, seconds?

Comment: You can edit your question to fix the source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: The big mix up here is that you used the term "stop" when you really wanted to use "sleep" - that's why this is a duplicate question. For those who really want a stop, your best bet is a stepper that runs over and over until the delay is reached. I'd post the code but this answer is closed.

Answer (score 148):

Before using this code, please read all comments.

Javascript is single-threaded, so by nature there should not be a sleep function because sleeping will block the thread. `setTimeout` is a way to get around this by posting an event to the queue to be executed later without blocking the thread. But if you want a true sleep function, you can write something like this:

```
function sleep(miliseconds) {
   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

   while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
   }
}
```

**Note:** The above code is **NOT** recommended.

Comment: **DONT LIKE THAT!!!** That causes WHOLE TAB freeze (also other tabs affected too) during that time , because `while` command is being executed unlimited times by CPU, causing to freeze. See practical example - https://jsfiddle.net/mn6yagqx/ (test yourself)

Comment: @T.Todua: That's why the post did not recommend it. This is just a workaround in case people want to do it anyway

Comment: I wonder how many people have used this block of code already without looking at the comment of @T.Todua

Comment: This was useful to simulate a very busy Web Worker, so I could confirm how messages get queued and processed when the worker is busy.

Comment: Still useful to introduce a temporary delay for debugging mocha tests, for example.

Comment: Should write a comment above the code block not to use this piece of code

Answer (score 72):

There's no (safe) way to pause execution. You can, however, do something like this using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout):

```
function writeNext(i)
{
    document.write(i);

    if(i == 5)
        return;

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        writeNext(i + 1);

    }, 2000);
}

writeNext(1);
```

Comment: This will not pause execution but delay `writeNext` function output. If there are lines of code after `writeNext(1);` they will be executed right away.

Answer (score 51):

You can use `setTimeout` to do this

```
function myFunction() {
    // your code to run after the timeout
}

// stop for sometime if needed
setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
```

Comment: Why are you passing myFunction as a callback?

Answer (score 6):

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep) might be helpful for you.

Every time I've wanted a sleep in the middle of my function, I refactored to use a setTimeout().

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to stop execution of your code as you would do with a procedural language. 
You can instead make use of setTimeout and some trickery to get a parametrized timeout:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var tick = function(i) {
        return function() {
            console.log(i);
        }
    };
    setTimeout(tick(i), 500 * i);
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hW7Ch/