# How to add delay to show a div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to "show" the hidden div after 2-3 sec delay. Is it possible in the same javascript? Help me please.......

**I've used the following code:**

```js
function ShowSecond() {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className = 'hide';
    }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.show {
      -o-transition: opacity 3s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
      transition: opacity 3s;
      opacity:1;
  }
  .hide {
      opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <style>
</style>
        <script>
            
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="div1" class="show">First Div
            <button onclick="ShowSecond()">clickMe</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="hide">Hidden Div</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

> I want to "show" the hidden div after 2-3 sec delay

Comment: You are doing it what is the problem with your code?

Comment: what is the problem? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/hca1690x/) it is working fine

Comment: When i click on the button the hidden div shows quickly, but i need to show the hidden div on button click after 2-3 seconds..

Comment: @Vishnu Which browser are you using? may be transitions aren't supported. Check my answer for a Javascript solution/workaround. :)

Comment: @Vishnu is your problem solved Already, or do you need some more help?

Comment: @winner - Actually its not solved, i just changed the design view. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a transition you will have to use some kind of css transition_(or *alot* of javascript calls, if your browser doesn't support css-transitions)_.

**Here a mini example, how to perform the transition with only javascript**
*Speed and duration for this typ of transition has to be done the the interval(here 250 ms) and the opacity step-size (here 0.1)*
*(With this settings the duration for showing the `div` is about **2.5 seconds**, since 250ms * 10 = 2.5s*

```js
function startShowing(){
  var elementToHide = document.getElementById("show");
  elementToHide.style.opacity = 0;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    if(elementToHide.style.opacity >= 1)
    {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }else{
      elementToHide.style.opacity = parseFloat(elementToHide.style.opacity) + 0.1;
    }
  },250);
}

//startShowing();
```

```css
.hide{
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide" id="show"> show me </div>
<button onclick="startShowing()"> SHOW </button>
```

*If you mean something else please specify your problem in more detail.*

***OLD Answer, probably not the intended solution***

**Just add** a *plus-sign* and a *space* when setting the `hide` css class to the `div`

With other words change this `div2.className = 'hide';` to this `div2.className += ' hide';` . Like this both classes are set on the `div` but the opacity value is overriden by the last added class

```js
function ShowSecond() {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className += ' hide';
    }, 2000);
    
}
```

```css
.show {
      -o-transition: opacity 3s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
      transition: opacity 3s;
      opacity:1;
  }
  .hide {
      opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <style>
</style>
        <script>
            
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="div1" class="show">First Div
            <button onclick="ShowSecond()">clickMe</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="hide">Hidden Div</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Like this the transition of the show is still valid and only the opacity is overriden.

Answer (score 1):

/*
 1. First you have to implementation on document ready function

2. Then delay function execution by (xxxx) ms

   $(document).ready(function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
            //what ever you want yo delay
       }, xxxx);
   });
   */

OR You will find the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624104/5924412) here

Comment: Just updated the answer .. someone asked that before

Comment: Is it the right method?------

function ShowSecond() {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className = 'hide';
    }, 2000);

//added the following

function ShowSecond() {
$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(function() { 2 }, ShowSecond); });
}

Answer (score 1):

use css property **transition-delay: 3s;** in show class

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

function ShowSecond() {

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create another function to call your function with your desired delay?

```
function ClickShowSecond(){
    setTimeout(ShowSecond, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Is it provide in the same js?

Comment: yes. It is. Put this function above your original function.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `setTimeout` and add delay accordingly.

```js
function ShowSecond() {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className = 'hide';
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className = 'show';
    }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.show {
      -o-transition: opacity 3s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
      transition: opacity 3s;
      opacity:1;
  }
  .hide {
      opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <style>
</style>
        <script>
            
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="div1" class="show">First Div
            <button onclick="ShowSecond()">clickMe</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="hide">Hidden Div</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className = 'hide';
        setTimeout(showDiv,3000);
    }, 2000);

function showDiv(){
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.className = 'show';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works on me, you can put the function in button trigger or when the page is load

```
// set this SetTimeout to your event trigger or in document ready 

setTimeout(showsomething, 3000);

function showsomething() {
//make your div or element being show here
}
```