# Is there a way to pause or delay an event handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, events, event-handling

I'm very new to **JavaScript** and trying to learn. I am using the ***StreamLabs API*** to display `gif animations` for *Twitch alerts*.

If alerts come in too quickly, the animation will keep cutting itself off and starting from the beginning. I'm trying to `delay` the events so that the animations will play fully.

Currently, the code snippet in question looks like this.

```js
streamlabs.on('event', (eventData) => 
  {
    var start = new Date();
    if (eventData.for === 'twitch_account') 
    {
      switch (eventData.type) 
      {
        case 'follow':
          //code to handle follow events
          console.log(eventData.message);
          setTimeout(function()
          {
            changeWithFollow();
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
              changeToDefault()
            }, followGifLength);
          }, start % 2500);
          break;
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Perhaps look at this? --> " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623852/how-to-pause-javascript-code-execution-for-2-seconds "

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise & SetTimeout to set delay:

```js
function delay(millseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('waiting...')
            resolve('waiting...')
        }, millseconds)
    })
}

async function test() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('start');
    await delay(2000);
    console.log('end');
}

test();
```