# How to set time delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this a piece of js in my website to switch images but need a delay when you click the image a second time. The delay should be 1000ms. So you would click the img.jpg then the img_onclick.jpg would appear. You would then click the img_onclick.jpg image there should then be a delay of 1000ms before the img.jpg is shown again.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".toggle-container").hide();
    $(".trigger").toggle(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".trigger").find('img').prop('src', 'http://localhost:8888/images/img_onclick.jpg');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(".trigger").find('img').prop('src', 'http://localhost:8888/images/img.jpg');
    });
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript)

Comment: possibly looking for `.stop()` though. Have a look here http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put a Delay in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript)

Answer (score 591, accepted):

Use **`setTimeout()`**:

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  //your code to be executed after 1 second
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

If you want to do it without `setTimeout`: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/).

Answer (score 94):

Below is sample code which uses ES6’s [async/await](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65) to resume execution of a function after a delay.

```js
const delay = (delayInms) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInms));
};

const sample = async () => {
  console.log('a');
  console.log('waiting...')
  let delayres = await delay(3000);
  console.log('b');
};
sample();
```

Answer (score 24):

There are two (mostly used) types of timer function in javascript `setTimeout` and `setInterval` ([other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers))

Both these methods have same signature. They take a call back function and delay time as parameter.

`setTimeout` executes only once after the delay whereas `setInterval` keeps on calling the callback function after every delay milisecs.

both these methods returns an integer identifier that can be used to clear them before the timer expires.

`clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` both these methods take an integer identifier returned from above functions `setTimeout` and `setInterval`

**Example:**

**[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)**

```
alert("before setTimeout");

setTimeout(function(){
        alert("I am setTimeout");
   },1000); //delay is in milliseconds 

  alert("after setTimeout");
```

If you run the the above code you will see that it alerts **`before setTimeout`** and then **`after setTimeout`** finally it alerts **`I am setTimeout`** after 1sec (1000ms)

What you can notice from the example is that the `setTimeout(...)` is asynchronous which means it doesn't wait for the timer to get elapsed before going to next statement i.e `alert("after setTimeout");`

**Example:**

**[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)**

```
alert("before setInterval"); //called first

 var tid = setInterval(function(){
        //called 5 times each time after one second  
      //before getting cleared by below timeout. 
        alert("I am setInterval");
   },1000); //delay is in milliseconds 

  alert("after setInterval"); //called second

setTimeout(function(){
     clearInterval(tid); //clear above interval after 5 seconds
},5000);
```

If you run the the above code you will see that it alerts **`before setInterval`** and then **`after setInterval`** finally it alerts **`I am setInterval`**  5 times after 1sec (1000ms) because the setTimeout clear the timer after 5 seconds or else every 1 second you will get alert **`I am setInterval`** Infinitely.

**How browser internally does that?**

I will explain in brief.

To understand that you have to know about event queue in javascript. There is a event queue implemented in browser. Whenever an event get triggered  in js, all of these events (like click etc.. ) are added to this queue.  When your browser has nothing to execute it takes an event from queue and executes them one by one.

Now,  when you call `setTimeout` or `setInterval` your callback get registered to an timer in browser and it gets added to the event queue after the given time expires and eventually javascript takes the event from the queue and executes it.

This happens so,  because javascript engine are single threaded and they can execute only one thing at a time. So,  they cannot execute other javascript and keep track of your timer. That is why these timers are registered with browser (browser are not single threaded) and it can keep track of timer and add an event in the queue after the timer expires.

same happens for `setInterval` only in this case the event is added to the queue again and again after the specified interval until it gets cleared or browser page refreshed.

> **Note**
>
> The delay parameter you pass to these functions is the minimum delay
>   time to execute the callback. This is because after the timer expires
>   the browser adds the event to the queue to be executed  by the
>   javascript engine but the execution of the callback depends upon your
>   events position in the queue and as the engine is single threaded it
>   will execute all the events in the queue one by one.

Hence, your callback may sometime take more than the specified delay time to be called specially when your other code blocks the thread and not giving it time to process what's there in the queue.

And as I mentioned javascript is single thread. So,  if you block the thread for long.

Like this code

```
while(true) { //infinite loop 
}
```

Your user may get a message saying **page not responding**.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I stop the asynchronous behavior of setTimeout()?

Comment: You don't use `setTimeout` if you don't want asynchronous behavior.

Answer (score 10):

For sync calls you can use the method below:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, setTimeOut didn't behave like this one I expect it to be. thanks!

Comment: calling setTimeout, even with a value of zero, will hand over control to the next item in the javascript event loop, so your code will effectively be paused until it's turn in the js event loop comes around again

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is a CPU-eating (= battery-eating) busy loop that will hang the page in a web browser, and it doesn’t even work reliably with the way it’s implemented here since different devices will count to the arbitrary 1e7 limit in different amounts of time. It’s practically never the right solution for a wait.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in JS domain but I've found a workaround for this problem using setTimeout() and a **recursive function** as follows:

```
i=0; //you should set i as a global variable
function recFunc() {
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        //do job1
    } else if (i == 2) {
        //do job2
    } else if (i == 3) {
        //do job3
    }
    if (i < 3) { //we have 3 distinct jobs. so the condition is (j < 3)
        setTimeout(function () {
            recFunc();
        }, 2000); //replace 2000 with desired delay
    }
}
//
//
//
recfunc(); //start the process
```

Answer (score 1):

### True Synchronous JavaScript Delay

**None of the above solutions are true JavaScript script delays as they are `asynchronous`.** An *asynchronous* function or callback script will not pause execution of other functions in the stack but will *continue running* while the asynchronous function, promise, observable, fetch, or other script starts.

Example: `setTimeout()` is an **asynchronous global function**...which means code keeps running after the setTimeout starts. In other words, you will **not** see a delay in your script from running, only a delay in the execution of the callback function inside the setTimeout.

If you do not want users from interacting with your page or script, you want a blocking `synchronous` script. Below is a synchronous code set that will *block* your pages global, *single-threaded JavaScript* code from running for 1 second, then resume after the delay.

```
        let datetime1 = new Date().getTime();
        let datetime2 = datetime1+1000;// 1 second delay

        while(datetime1<datetime2) {
            datetime1 = new Date().getTime();
        }
```