# how to add processing time in this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(function() {
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
$( "#revocation" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 200,
  width: 460,
  modal: true,
  buttons:{
    "Yes": function() {
      revocation();
    },
    "Close" : function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

I want to put  add processing time in  this function, when I click the button "Yes", add processing time of 3-5 seconds, thank you in advance

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: when i click button "Yes" , in function revocation can add time slow or not ?

Comment: I think what you are really asking is how to add a time delay to a function so you can emulate processing time. See this post - [How to set time delay in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883692/how-to-set-time-delay-in-javascript)

Comment: you see my picture for more ,can add function , when i click button " yes "  appear 2 files  "revocation" in chrome with latency time: 410ms & 309ms ,    there a way to add jquery make one click button 2 file to run equal  not, eg: 410ms & 410ms.  (  http://i.stack.imgur.com/HUDaC.jpg ) thank you

Comment: can you show full listing?

Comment: I've updated, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronyous language. You can put

```
setTimeout(function() {revocation();},3000);
```

instead of

```
revocation();
```

for delay in 3000 msec

Comment: I need your help for one problem .  thank you advance .

Answer (score 0):

you see my picture for more ,can add function , when i click button " yes "  appear 2 files  "revocation" in chrome with latency time: 410ms & 309ms ,    there a way to add jquery make one click button 2 file to run equal  not, eg: 410ms & 410ms.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUDaC.jpg)