# Scrolling down after a few seconds to an anchor

Tags: javascript, time, scroll, anchor, smoothing

I wonder if it's possible to scroll down after 6 seconds to an anchor?

I found this script where it scrolls down a couple of pixels but it's not completely what I'm looking for.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     setTimeout("window.scrollBy(0,270);",6000);
</script>
```

Also how can i make it scroll down smoothly? I found this but how do i combine it with the other script?

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
     var aTag = $("a[name='" + aid + "']");
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("#link").click(function() {
     scrollToAnchor('id3');
});
```

I'm not very familiar with JS so I would really appreciate some help :)

the site I'm working is: [kip.mascomm.be](http://kip.mascomm.be)

UPDATE:

I got the first part to work, thanks to Seth, but can someone please give me a code to make the performance smooth:

```
var delay = 1000 * 10;
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.hash = "#kippenkramen";
    }, delay);
```

Answer (score 2):

Time Delay example:

```
var delay=1000 * 6;//1*6 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  //window.scrollTo(500, 0);//scrolls to specific location
  //location.hash = "#elmentid"; //scrolls to element with given id
},delay);
```

([How to set time delay in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883692/how-to-set-time-delay-in-javascript))

Animated Scrolling function:

```
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
  if (duration < 0) return;
  var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
  var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    if (element.scrollTop == to) return;
    scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
  }, 10);
}
```

([Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation))

Comment: thanks Seth!
The time delay thing with location.hash worked:
    var delay=1000 * 10;
    setTimeout(function(){ location.hash = "#kippenkramen"; },delay); 

I pasted the animated scrolling function under the other script but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach( el => {
    el.onclick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location = el.getAttribute('href')
      }, 6000);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you check out [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for the future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.