# Auto Scroll to #ID1 #ID2 #ID3 in X time

Tags: php, jquery

how are you?

I was wondering how to Automaticly Scroll (without touching anything) from ID #one to ID #two and ID #three in X amount of time.

Like, when the page LOADS it loads into ID #one but after 5 secs need to scroll to ID #two and after 5 seconds to ID #three

How can i do this?

Im using wordpress so i can use jQuery or JavaScript

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would try checking out [mcve] first.

Comment: And here's a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775133/scrolling-down-after-a-few-seconds-to-an-anchor) that might get you going.