# Add a time delay between to actions of the same function?

Tags: javascript, function, timer, delay

I have a button which when clicked performs myFunction with two actions, i'd like it to perform the first action, wait for 2 seconds, then perform the action. This is the code so far:

```
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('box1').style.display = "block"; $("#box2").data( "mmenu" ).close();
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883692/how-to-set-time-delay-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep in Javascript - delay between actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript-delay-between-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** for providing delay

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('box1').style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    // code to execute after delay
    $("#box2").data("mmenu").close();
  }, 2000);
  // -^- delay in milliseconds 
};
```