# Javascript run after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, timeout

I am new to Javascirpt. What exactly should I add to the code below so that`this.callHandler('ok');` will only run after `10` seconds

```
Window_NameInput.prototype.processHandling = function() {
    if (this.isOpen() && this.active) {
        this.callHandler('ok');
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set time delay in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883692/how-to-set-time-delay-in-javascript) and [Execute script after specific delay using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `this.callHandler('ok')` with a function and pass it to `setTimeout()`. Pass `10000` as second parameter because it takes time in milliseconds.

```
Window_NameInput.prototype.processHandling = function() {
    if (this.isOpen() && this.active) {
        setTimeout(() => this.callHandler('ok'),10000); 
    }
};
```

Comment: what my code will do is close a window inside a game. but after using your code, it close the whole game, instead of a window inside a game. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Tosps Can't say anything without seeing your code. But my code only delay `this.callHandler('ok')` for 10 seconds. There might be some problem in `this.callHandler`

Comment: I think it's might be because I didn't clear timeout. how do you clear timeout for this? Thanks

Comment: @Tosps You don't need to `clearTimeout` it will only occur once. but if you want to stop it before even happening once you can use `clearTimeout()`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Maybe because if (this.isOpen() && this.active) ,  it is always checking if the window is open , so when timeout it repeats itself and keeps closing too many times?

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out the reason, if I don't set timeout , this.callHandler('ok'); runs once, if I set timeout it repeats

Comment: if I put
setTimeout(() => alert("alert") ,10000);   it keeps alerting repeatedly

Comment: @Tosps Then this mean you are calling this function repeatdly

Comment: I see what's happening.  In my original code this.callHandler('ok')  was supposed to repeat, but before it can run the second time, it already disabled the" if window is open" condition. So it won't run anymore. How come setTimeout(() => this.callHandler('ok'),10000);  will not disable the " if window is open" condition the first time? insteading it just keeps going.