# How do I add a delay or a wait before the JS code fires?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delay, wait

I am wondering if someone could help me with an issue that I am having.

I have a call tracking SAAS program that I use that calls the client when a webform is filled out and lead is created (Name, E-mail, Phone). When the form is submitted the software calls the client asking them to press 1 to be connected to the lead. When they press 1 the software then proceeds to call the lead. This works flawlessly for normal leads.

However I am wanting to use it on a Lead Generating funnel where I have a secondary offer on the thank you page. I am wanting the code to wait  or delay for 60 seconds so they have time to read the secondary offer.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Maurice

Here is the JS code to get the SAAS program to fire the call.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dialhawk.com/fc/5e375706301f3/call.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`setTimeout()`:**

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  //your code to be executed after 1 second
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883692/how-to-set-time-delay-in-javascript)

Comment: Tried that and couldn't get it to work

Comment: What are you trying exactly? Can you show me your code?