# jquery delay the execution of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

In my jquery function I have a loader gif image. After I show it I want to put a delay for a second and then continue to execute the rest of the code. 
How can I do that?

```
    $('#loader').css('display', '');

    //// I want to put here a delay. 

    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(2013,8,2);

    var checkyear = myDate.getFullYear();
    var monthly =myDate.getMonth();
    var daily =myDate.getDate();

    $('#day').html(daily) ;
    $('#month').html(months[monthly]) ;
    $('#year').html(checkyear) ;
```

Comment: check `window.setTimeout()` in JS docs of your choice

Comment: check this answer out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript

Comment: Please use the search functionality on stackoverflow next time before you post a question that has been asked (and answered) like a zillion times

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set a timeout like this :

```
var delay = 1000;
setTimeout(function() {
 // your code
}, delay);
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/HuLTs/

Comment: No problem on Chrome for me. Create a new topic with your question.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) ?

```
$('#loader').show(1).delay(1000).hide(1);
```

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout) function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/SBrWa/

Comment: `$('#loader').show().delay(1000).hide(0);` would be enough ;) +1 for showing alternative. Just as an inside, DOC concerning delay() seems no more to be accurate. Looks like a delay() can be canceled using jq 1.9 method .finish()

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      //your code
     },
  2000); 
});
```

Here **`2000`** refers to  **`2 seconds`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
$('#loader').css('display', '');

setTimeout(function() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(2013,8,2);

    var checkyear = myDate.getFullYear();
    var monthly =myDate.getMonth();
    var daily =myDate.getDate();

    $('#day').html(daily) ;
    $('#month').html(months[monthly]) ;
    $('#year').html(checkyear) ;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('#loader').css('display', '');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setFullYear(2013,8,2);
        var checkyear = myDate.getFullYear();
        var monthly =myDate.getMonth();
        var daily =myDate.getDate();
        $('#day').html(daily) ;
        $('#month').html(months[monthly]) ;
        $('#year').html(checkyear) ;
    },1000);// 1 second delay
});
```