# Changing the Z-Index of a Div After Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a New Tab extension for Chrome, and, as part of it, need to change the z-index 3 seconds after page load. I have tried JavaScript, CSS and HTML, but cannot find the right code.

I am also very new to programming, and so any code posted would be a great assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how extensions to Chrome work, but if injecting JavaScript is an option then it's literally a matter of waiting until the document is loaded (Examples here: [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load) )

Then waiting some time (Examples here: [Put a Delay in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript))

Then simply setting the z-index of the element you want to edit.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=newIndex;
```

However if what you're trying to do is some sort of animation, there are far more effective ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("elementID").style.zIndex="1"
}, 3000);
```

or jQuery solution

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#elementID').css({ zIndex: '1' });
}, 3000);
```

***Note:** You must include [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/download/) if you decide to use jQuery solution.