# Controlling speed of loop processing

Tags: javascript

Here is problem,
I have some `java code` that `runs` on a `server` and every `60seconds` selects `60seconds` worth of data, **constructs an object** out of each one and then adds it to a list.

Now on the `client side` i have some `javascript` that **calls a methods on the server** and returns this **list of object**. these objects each represents a image that needs to move to a certain location on the screen.

Now here comes the problem im currently facing. I have about **60seconds to loop** through these objects and animate the image to the right location. Now when I try loop through it almost does the loop instantly and all the images just appears at the starting location. What this tells me is the **function** i call to do the animation doesn't get time to complete as another call to that function is interrupting it.

How does one go about **controlling** this so that no matter what the size I always finish the list in **60seconds?**

ps... I have tried `setTimeout` to no avail
procedural client side really not my stronger side

### As Requested, the json that is received is an array of objects

```
function dataServer() {
          $.getJSON("/service/data/message", function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    msgs = data;
                            check = true;
                            counter = 0;
                            var total = data.length;
                            waitTime = (60000 / total) - (8 * delay);
                            for(var message in data) {
                                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-54.75, 148);
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                                    position: latLng,
                                                                    map: map,
                                                                    optimized: true,
                                                                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( image , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(85, 60))
                                                                    });
                                position = [-55, 148];
                                result = [ data[message].x, data[message].y ];
                                i = 0;
                                deltaLat = (result[0] - position[0])/numDeltas;
                                deltaLng = (result[1] - position[1])/numDeltas;
                                var w = 85;
                                var h = 60;
                                var shrinkW = w / 2;
                                var shrinkH = h /2;
                                var shrinkDeltaW = shrinkW / numDeltas;
                                var shrinkDeltaH = shrinkH / numDeltas;
                                var deltaW = w / numDeltas;
                                var deltaH = h / numDeltas;
                                var toSet = true;

                                function moveMarker(result){
                                    position[0] += deltaLat;
                                    position[1] += deltaLng;

                                    if(i % 4 == 0) {                    
                                        w -= deltaW;
                                        h -= deltaH;
                                    }

                                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1]);
                                    marker.setPosition(latlng);
                                    marker.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage( image , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(w, h)));

                                    if(i == (numDeltas - 1)) {
                                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[message].x, data[message].y);
                                        marker.setPosition(latlng);
                                        i++;
                                    }

                                    if(i!=numDeltas){
                                        i++;
                                        if(markerArray.length > 10) {
                                            shrinkW -= shrinkDeltaW;
                                            shrinkH -= shrinkDeltaH;
                                            markerArray[0].setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage( image , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(shrinkW, shrinkH)));
                                            if(i == (numDeltas -1)) {
                                                markerArray[0].setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage( image , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(85, 60)));
                                                markerArray[0].setMap(null);
                                                markerArray.splice(markerArray[0], 1);
                                                feature = map.data.getFeatureById(dataArray[0].countryCode);
                                                if (feature) {
                                                    feature.setProperty('colour', dataArray[0].opacity);
                                                } else {
                                                }
                                                dataArray.splice(dataArray[0], 1);
                                            }

                                        }
                                        delay = waitTime / 8;
                                        setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
                                    } 

                                }

                                moveMarker(result);

                                markerArray.push(marker);
                                dataArray.push(data[message]);


                            }


                } else {


                    dataServer();
                }


          }); 

        if(check == false) {
            counter++;
            if(counter == 100) {
                window.location.href = "/intermission.htm";
            }   
        }

        check = false;
    }
```

Comment: [Put a Delay in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript)??

Comment: I am currently using setTimeout on a couple of places. Let me clarify bait better, I have a get request on a loop that runs every 60 seconds. This populates a list of objects, I then get the length of the list and divide by 60sec to get the required delay and then loop over the list putting the delay time as a timeout. yet the delay isn't happening as every item in the list seems to appear almost at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval() like you said and then break the loop when this interval expires.
Like:

```
var stop = false,
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        stop = true;
    }, 60000);

var items = []; // your list.
for(var i=0, y=items.length; i<y; i++){
    // Do stuff

    if(stop){ break; }
}
```

Comment: With the interval set it does pause, yet for some reason only one of the items in the list of 161 appears on the screen. Its like the javascript runs over the loop to fast and then only displays the last item in the list.

Comment: I think you need to add some example code to make things more clear.