# Automatically clearing Facebook timeline with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i would like to clear my old post in my Facebook timeline.
 I have tried using JS to automate this operation, but I am not able  to make  the goal.
 The strange thing, for me, is that if I try the single steps they works fine, when I put all together it doesn't work.

1. Selecting the Story options button to open the menu (it works)
2. Clicking the “Delete” item in the submenu, it works putting a little delay,
3. Selecting - and clicking - the  confirm button to delete the post (it doesn't workss)

   Trying to selecting the Confirm button (Delete Post) it is null. 
   But if I try to execute  the step no. 3 after 1 and 2 it works.

   This is my code, I run it from the Firefox Scratchpad (Shift+F4) in a specific  year section of the timeline (click on a year on facebook.com/me)

```
// Replace these values if your locale in FB is different from en-US  
let l10nALabel="Story options";
let l10nDelete = "Delete";
let l10nCButton = "Delete Post";
// Change this value if the script doesn't works properly
let delay = 1000;
function sleep(delay) {
    // Code snippet  taken from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascrip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}

getElementByText = function(selector, text){
    els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (i=0; i<els.length; i++) if ((els[i].textContent==text) && (els[i].children.length==0))   break;
    if (i==els.length) return null;
    else return els[i];
}

deletePost = function(post, delay){
    post.click();
    sleep(delay);
    let delb = getElementByText("span", l10nDelete);
    console.log(delb);
    delb.click();
    sleep(delay);
    let cb = getElementByText("button", l10nCButton);
    console.log(cb);
    cb.click();
}

let a = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="' + l10nALabel + '"]')
deletePost(a[0], delay);
```

Comment: @Mark Stroeven
I know that exists APIs to do these things, but I was searching the fastest, and simplest, way to do this, not the best possible. 
My goal is not to release an add-on/GMscript to clear the timeline but only to remove quickly all my post.
Using APIs requires to write good code, and I am not a JS developer, and creating API keys, instead the few lines written above requires for me only some minutes.
But I have asked the question because I am wondered of the strange behavior (it works for single steps but not when are put together) and your reply is what I am searching :-)
Thanks

Comment: Well if you really want to do this in a bad way, try looking at selenium to generate your code :) http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using javascript to automate commands is not the proper way to do this!** Facebook has built in security measures for these practices, and should you succeed in doing it your way the main question qould be why would you do it in such a inefficient way.

We have API's / libraries (official ones) for a reason. You should use the facebook graph API for doing such things. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api