# Div Slideshow (html, css, js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting my journey in creating webpages. I crave something to try to imitate windows 10 start UI as well as there animation on browser. But the problem is that I'm not yet knowledgeable with javascript. If you dont mind please do check my codes for some problems. Thank you.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WinCalc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="slideShow()">
    <form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="holder">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="savButtondesc">
                    <div id="savDesc"> Sum, Average & Max</div>
                    <div id="savDesc1"> Display Sum, Average & Max of the number inputted.</div>
                </div>
                <input id="savButton" type="button" name="sav">


            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: RobotoL;
    src:url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#holder {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #34495e;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 24%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
#savButton {
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #3498db;
    position: relative;
    opacity: .1;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#savButtondesc {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
#savDesc {
    width: 100;
    margin-top: 17%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    font-family: RobotoL;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    transition: 1s;
}
#savDesc1 {
    font-family: RobotoL;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;

}
```

JavaScript

```
    function slideShow() {
    setInterval( function show(){
        var next = 0;
        if (next == 0) {
            animate();
            next++:
        }
        else {
            reverse();
            next--;
        }
    },1000);

}
function animate(){
        document.getElementById('samDesc').style.marginTop = "-2%";
        document.getElementById('samDesc1').style.marginTop = "25%";
        document.getElementById('samDesc1').style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById('samDesc').style.opacity = "0";
}
function reverse(){
        document.getElementById('samDesc').style.marginTop = "17%";
        document.getElementById('samvDesc1').style.marginTop = "-55%";
        document.getElementById('samDesc1').style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById('samDesc').style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *"please do check my codes for some problem"* - Please [edit] your question to describe more clearly the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour. When you run your code what happens? (Nothing? Something, but the wrong thing? Are there errors in the browser's dev console?)

Comment: sorry about that. what i really want to express is that, when animate() done executing, after 1000 of ms the reverse() well take place. something like this animate() wait 1 sec and then reverse() and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Use slideShow(); at the end of your javascript code.

Anyway, I recommend you to use http://unslider.com/ as a jQuery plugin.

Comment: He calls the function in the onload attribute of body so if he does call it at the end of his js, he would have duplicated the call.

Comment: My bad. I didn't fully understand what he is trying to do.

Comment: some what looping? when animate() done executing , wait for 1 sec then reverse() will do . and repeat.

Comment: Ya, my bad dude, I didn't understand what you were trying to do. You can do that with setTimeout function, source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript and then use the reverse funtion.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check this code now working you define the wrong semicolon symbol the next++; and element id is wrong in js wrong i have fixed this issue check now this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WinCalc</title>
  <style>

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#holder {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #34495e;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 24%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
#savButton {
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #3498db;
    position: relative;
    opacity: .1;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#savButtondesc {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
#savDesc {
    width: 100;
    margin-top: 17%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    font-family: RobotoL;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    transition: 1s;
}
#savDesc1 {
    font-family: RobotoL;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;

} 
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript" > 
function slideShow() {  
 var next = 0;
 setInterval( function show(){ 
    if (next == 0) {
        animate();
        next++;
    }
    else {
        reverse();
        next--;
    }
},1000);

}
function animate(){ 
    document.getElementById('savDesc').style.marginTop = "-2%";
    document.getElementById('savDesc1').style.marginTop = "25%";
    document.getElementById('savDesc1').style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById('savDesc').style.opacity = "0";
}
function reverse(){
    document.getElementById('savDesc').style.marginTop = "17%";
   // document.getElementById('samvDesc1').style.marginTop = "-55%";
    document.getElementById('savDesc1').style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById('savDesc').style.opacity = "1";
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="slideShow()">
    <form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="holder">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="savButtondesc">
                    <div id="savDesc"> Sum, Average & Max</div>
                    <div id="savDesc1"> Display Sum, Average & Max of the number inputted.</div>
                </div>
                <input id="savButton" type="button" name="sav"> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the setInterval function in slideShow(), put either

```
setInterval('animate()', 1000);
```

Or

```
setInterval(animate, 1000);
```