# Adding a 2 seconds delay between javascript lines

Tags: javascript

I want to animate something everytime I click on it. So I saved an animation in the class "animation".

```
function listClick() {
  toplist.classList.add("animation");
  toplist.classList.remove("animation");
}
```

the animation lasts 2000 ms so I want a delay of 2000 ms between those two lines of code in my function. How can I achieve this using Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put a Delay in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function listClick() {
     toplist.classList.add("animation");
     setTimeout(function() {
          toplist.classList.remove("animation");
     }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a function for this, I just couldn't find the name. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have the `setTimeout(function(), timeoutInMilliSecs);` you can throw in there and use.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function listClick() {
    toplist.classList.add("animation");
    await sleep(2000);
    toplist.classList.remove("animation");
}
```

[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)