# How to simulate a delay like some chat bots do?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a little interaction on a page that acts kind of like a very simple bot.

How can I simulate a little time delay like you see in bots?  (when it shows a 'typing...' indicator or that image with dots that animates).

Comment: Have you tried using `setTimeout`?

Comment: This question is sort of on the cusp of being too broad... but a using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with a random interval would be my starting point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put a Delay in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript)

Comment: Add element with css style of loading svg with animation, then use setTimeout after which you remove the svg loading element and append the answer.

Comment: you don't need `settimeout` just display 3 dots animation, at the begining of the method, then when the bot is finished removed the dots from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` like below.

```js
startDelay = (timeDelay) => {
  console.log(`It's time to go`);
  setTimeout(() => {
     console.log('I wake up');
  }, timeDelay);
};

startDelay(3000);
```